# Convert a Binary String longer than 8 into a single unicode character

Tags: c#, .net, encoding, binary, type-conversion

I need to convert a string into binary and back.
But when the input is an `Unicode Character` the resulting Binary String is longer than 8 characters and converting it back using `Convert.ToByte` causes an `Overflow Exception`.
I used the `Convert.ToString` method to convert the String into Binary.

```
String input = "⌓" //Unicode Character
String binary = Convert.ToString(input, 2); //Convert to Binary 
                                           //->> Returns "10001100010011"
byte re = Convert.ToByte("10001100010011", 2); //This causes an Overflow Exception 
//What should I do here? Is there a better reverse of Convert.ToString than Convert.ToByte?
```

Is there an alternative or something similar?

Comment: `Convert.ToInt16`? It is 2 bytes long.

Comment: `Convert.ToString(Char.ConvertToUtf32(input, 0), 2)`; `Char.ConvertFromUtf32(Convert.ToInt32(..., 2))`, if you want to cover all of Unicode and don't want to treat surrogates specially.

Comment: Thank you Jeroen it works great

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the problem here is that a byte is only 8 bits. You are putting in a string with 14 bits in it. Try using Convert.ToUint16() and declare "re" as Uint16 like so:

```
UInt16 re = Convert.ToUInt16("10001100010011", 2); 
// UInt16 is large enough to hold the data

Console.WriteLine(re); // prints 8979

//unicode decimal 8979: http://www.codetable.net/decimal/8979
```